# Launch Windows 8 apps in the simulator (or Launch Simulator with windows 8 app as parameter)

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps

When debugging a windows store app it is possible to [Run Windows Store apps in the simulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh441475.aspx#BKMK_Set_the_simulator_as_the_target). This a very nify option, as it runs windowed with increased functionality (simulating touch interaction from mouse control etc).

Example of app being run in the simulator:

[image: Example of app being run in simulator]

Now, what I can do is go to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\11.0` and run `Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe` and then open my windows store app.

Is it possible to have a normal launch open up the simulator and run the app there?

It is possible to make a batch file to launch the simulator with parameters to open the app of my choosing? Something like: `start C:\"Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\11.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe" --launch something`

Comment: By normal launch, do you mean directly clicking the app from start?

Comment: @MarioStoilov Sorry, yeah, that's what I mean. Although I suspect the solution will be to replace the shortcut to the apps with short cuts to the simulators that pass in the apps.

Comment: Why automate this at all when it's only a couple clicks away?

The simulator copies whatever settings you have in your machine so set up your windows start screen or desktop, (or startup programs) to easily launch the app you want.
I don't know enough about why you would to batch file this operation, unless you are doing this A LOT then I doubt it will be worth it.

1. Create a shortcut to open the simulator
2. Have a tile on the homescreen or desktop/task bar which opens your app.